# How to change separator color for UITableView only for first row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    } else {
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

I have the above code to change the separator color for only first row. However, the whole section itself turns out with a clear color separator instead of blue. Could you please help me with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `separatorColor` is a property of `UITableView` and it affects the whole table.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm setting the `UITableView` property back in the else block right? Moreover, for other `indexPath.section`s since I'm not using this code, I'm getting the default separator.

Comment: When you set `separatorColor` it applies to all cells. Nothing about that property applies to any one specific cell.

Comment: If you want a different color "separator line" you will need to set `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`, then add a "line" to your cell (usually a 1-pt tall `UIView` at the bottom of the cell)... then set the `.backgroundColor` of the "line" view in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use tableview default seperator.

`tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
or 
tableView.separatorStyle = .none`

In `UITableViewCell` add a `UIView` of 1 px height, give that whatever color you want. If same `UITableViewCell` is used for all the table rows, then might be you can use something like -

`seperatorView.hidden = indexPath.row != 0`